# Android Studio does not start from launcher

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and installed android studio. The Android studio starts perfectly from command line. I created a desktop entry for convenience. When I start it from the launcher it gives me the 'Android Studio Setup Wizard'. It tries to download components but failed with "The following SDK components were not installed: extra-android-m2repository and extra-google-m2repository" error message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I also faced this issue previously, Simple skip this step.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this Issue too...

When it fails go to launcher -> Rt. Click -> Quit.

Then it comes a popup re-run the set-up wizard, Click NO.

The next time you launch it directly asks you to create new Project or Open an Existing Project

Answer (score 0):

I've just install the new release 1.3 today and faced exactly the same thing ):

Open the "**SDK Manager.exe**" from the SDK folder and check
**Android Support Repository** and **Android Support Library**, then install these 2 packages. Make sure you **accept license** on when the next window appears.

Restart the IDE and feel the change :)